# Inno Setup: Log registry item creation

Tags: inno-setup

I can tell Inno Setup (tried with the latest version 5.5.9) to create log file by launching `setup.exe /log=<log.txt>`.

Unfortunately, it does not seem to log creation of registry entries declared in the `[Registry]` section. How to tell Inno Setup to also log the registry entry creation or reasons why they were not created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make Inno Setup automatically log actions based on `[Registry]` section.

But you can log them manually using [`BeforeInstall` and `AfterInstall` parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) and [`Log` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_log):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "Test"; ValueData: "data"; \
  BeforeInstall: Log('Before writing Test value'); \
  AfterInstall: Log('After writing Test value');
```

Registry writing errors (as any errors) are logged automatically:

```
2017-05-21 16:57:51.652   Before writing Test value
2017-05-21 16:57:51.653   Message box (Abort/Retry/Ignore):
                          Error creating registry key:
                          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\My Company\My Program

                          RegCreateKeyEx failed; code 5.
                          Access is denied.

                          Click Retry to try again, Ignore to proceed anyway, or Abort to cancel installation.
2017-05-21 17:00:58.116   User chose Ignore.
2017-05-21 17:00:58.116   After writing Test value
```

---

If you need greater control over the logging, you need to use Pascal Scripting (instead of `[Registry]` section entries) to write to the registry. But you cannot use convenient Inno Setup Registry [support functions](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions), as they won't give you a reason of a failure.

You would have to use low-level WinAPI functions.

Some references:

- Use of low-level Registry WinAPI functions in Inno Setup: [How to access registry of a remote machine in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7830652/850848#7836170);
- Logging of WinAPI errors: [Inno Setup FileCopy failing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39535942/850848#39581869).